# How to add settings for specific Lambdas based on which repository they're being deployed from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to change the maximum-event-age setting for Lambdas using a bash script. Serverless does not currently appear to support this setting, so I'm planning to do it as a bash script after a deploy from GitHub.

Approach:

I'm considering querying aws for the Lambdas in a specific CloudFormation stack. I'm guessing that when a repo is deployed, a new CF stack is created. Then, I want to iterate over the functions and use the `put-function-event-invoke-config` to change the maximum-event-age setting on each lambda.

Problem:

The `put-function-event-invoke-config` seems to require a function name. When querying for CF stacks, I'm getting the lambda ARNs instead. I could possibly do some string manipulation to get just the lambda name, but it seems like a messy way to do it.

Am I on the right track with this? Is there a better way?

Edit:

The lambdas already exist and have been deployed. What I think I need to do is run some kind of script that is able to go through the list of lambdas that have been deployed from a single repository (there are multiple repos being deployed to the same environment) and change the maximum-event-age setting that has a default of 6 hours.

Here's an example output when I use the CLI to query CFN with `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` :

```
 {
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:***:stack/my-repository-name/0sdg70gfs-6124-12ea-a910-93c4ahj3d140",
        "StackName": "my-repository-name",
        "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
        "CreationTime": "2019-11-18T22:05:44.246Z",
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2019-03-19T23:26:04.382Z",
        "RollbackConfiguration": {},
        "StackStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
        "DisableRollback": false,
        "NotificationARNs": [],
        "Capabilities": [
            "CAPABILITY_IAM",
            "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
        ],
        "Outputs": [
            {
                "OutputKey": "TestLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn",
                "OutputValue": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:my-test-function:3",
                "Description": "Current Lambda function version"
            },
```

I know that it is possible to run this command to change the maximum-event-age:

```
$ aws lambda --region us-east-1 put-function-event-invoke-config --function-name my-test-function --maximum-event-age-in-seconds 3600
```

But it appears to require the `--function-name` which I don't see in the CFN output in the query above.

How do I programmatically go through all of the functions in a CFN stack and modify the settings for maximum-event-age?

Comment: CFN does return lambda function name, using [!Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#aws-resource-lambda-function-return-values).

Comment: I just read through the docs and I don't understand how to use Ref. Could you please explain it further? I'm very new to this

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure what you are doing. Your description is very confusing. So you are using CloudFormation to create your lambda? Can you provide the template you use. To output function name from the template you use `Outputs` section in the template.

Comment: @Marcin I've updated the question to hopefully make it more clear. I'm also not sure what you mean by template. Is that the Serverless yaml file? Let me know if it's still unclear as to what it is I'm trying to do. Thanks for being so patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put-function-event-invoke-config` accepts ARNs, which means one could query CFN based on stack-names which would correspond to the repo that it was deployed from.

However, I decided to use `list-functions` to query for Lambdas and then `list-tags` because our deploys are tagged by repo names. It seemed like a better option than to query CFN (also CFN output ARNs contain a suffix which means `put-function-event-invoke-config` won't run on them).

Then I can run the text output through a for loop in bash and use `put-function-event-invoke-config` to add the maximum-event-age setting.